# Find all possible combinations of items in array of arrays

Tags: python, arrays

I have an array of arrays that looks like this:

```
arrays = [['a', 'b'], [1, 2], ['x', 'y', 'z']]
```

but could also be expanded.

I need to feed these to `my_function(a_or_b, one_or_two, x_y_or_x)` in all of their possible combinations (`a 1 x`, `a 2 x`, `a 1 y`, `a 1 z`, ecc). Using numpy is an option.

Though it appears as a simple problem, I have no idea where to start...

Yes, I could loop like:

```
for array in arrays:
    for ...
```

and then what? Looping through the arrays means that on my second iteration `arrays[0]` would no longer be first and I'd mess up the order. I also would have duplicates.

How can I do this? I don't care in which order these functions are called, but I do care that they're not called twice with the same combination and that the arguments are in order.

```
my_function(a, 1, x)
my_function(b, 1, x)
my_function(a, 2, x)
my_function(b, 2, x)
my_function(a, 1, y)
my_function(b, 1, y)
my_function(a, 2, y)
ecc...
```

Comment: Try `itertools.product` or one of the other very useful tools in itertools

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) does exactly this. It will generate all combinations from your 3 sublists. Then you can unpack them as arguments in your function:

```
from itertools import product

combs = product(*arrays)
for comb in combs:
    my_function(*comb)
```

Calls

```
my_function('a', 1, 'x')
my_function('a', 1, 'y')
my_function('a', 1, 'z')
my_function('a', 2, 'x')
my_function('a', 2, 'y')
my_function('a', 2, 'z')
my_function('b', 1, 'x')
my_function('b', 1, 'y')
my_function('b', 1, 'z')
my_function('b', 2, 'x')
my_function('b', 2, 'y')
my_function('b', 2, 'z')
```